# SED - Search two pattern in a line and insert few word at the end of the line if pattern match is found

Tags: sed

I have a file  and i want to search two pttern in the same line  and if found one word should be inserted at the end of the line. want to do in a sed .

Example

I have a file contents like below , want to search unix and NotOK

```
abc unix windows DBa NotOK 
abc unix windows DBa OK
abc oracle sybase java OK
```

output should be like (Match abc and NotOK and if found , insert unix at the end of the line)

```
abc unix windows DBa NotOK "unix"
abc unix windows DBa OK
abc oracle sybase java OK
```

Comment: please always put what you have tried till now in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[bash_prompt$]]$ cat log
abc unix windows DBa NotOK
abc unix windows DBa OK
abc oracle sybase java OK
[[bash_prompt$]]$ sed -e 's/^.*unix.*NotOK.*$/& "unix"/g' log
abc unix windows DBa NotOK  "unix"
abc unix windows DBa OK
abc oracle sybase java OK
```

Comment: Thank You very much abasu , its relly helpfull. appreaciate your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed "/Pattern1/ {/Pattern2/ s/$/ YourLastWork/;}" ${YourFile}
```

in this case, order of pattern is not specify (both have to be present)

Answer (score 1):

I know its asked for `sed`, but just to show how to do it in `awk`

```
awk '/abc.*NotOK/ {$0=$0 "\"unix\""}1' log
abc unix windows DBa NotOK "unix"
abc unix windows DBa OK
abc oracle sybase java OK
```

If order of abc and NotOK may vary, you can do

```
awk '/abc/ && /NotOK/ {$0=$0 "\"unix\""}1' log
```

Comment: I like `$++NF=x` for appending fields, it honors `OFS`