# Sed - Print Lines that match two patterns

Tags: perl, sed, match

i have the following problem. My file looks like this :

```
1082016051300000010005690902BCDEΔ0204366221002201612052016-00001274448A                                                                     
1082016051300000010034397704EDFG10865125102001201626042016-000001028134
1082016051300000010068901401RADJ34835974123112201528042016-000001343290                                                                     
1082016051300000010068901401RADJ34835974103112201528042016-000000910290                                                                     
1082016051300000010095474301RADJ13453401102812201525042016-00000208995K                                                                     
1082016051300000010098429002RADJΤ1052947211312201218042016-000034021290
1032016051300000010095474301RADJ13453401102812201525042016-00000208995K                                                                     
1032016051300000010098429002RADJΤ1052947211312201218042016-000034021290
```

and i m trying to print only lines that match both patterns, anywhere on the line. I want to print only lines that match two patterns, the first pattern being on columbs 2:1 (08) and the second pattern being the word (RAD). I ve tried to do this with grep :

```
grep -o '.[0-1][1-8]*RAD' FILEIN
```

and the only response i get is that FILEIN is a binary file. I ve also tried with sed this :

```
sed -n '/[0-1][1-8]*RAD/p' FILEIN
```

but i have a feelign the * is not expanded. I ve managed to make it work by looking for two patterns in succession, like :

```
sed -n '/RAD/p' FILEIN | sed '/^108/p'
```

and this works, but the file i ll be using as input is potentially huge, and i m not sure that piping a stream into another is time efficient. Could someone help me? Awk or Perl are welcome too. Thank you

Comment: Please visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700002/sed-search-two-pattern-in-a-line-and-insert-few-word-at-the-end-of-the-line-if) for already answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `-a` option to `grep` to force it to read a file as text.

`sed` is a scripting language; you can combine multiple conditions and actions easily.

```
sed -n '/regex1/!d;/regex2/p' files...
```

(If no match on the first regex, delete this line and take the next one. Otherwise, if it matches the second regex, print.)

The same is also easy -- perhaps even easier -- in Awk.

```
awk '/regex1/ && /regex2/' files...
```

Comment: Not all `sed` dialects like the semicolon statement separator. If this is a problem for you, try with a newline instead, or passing multiple `-e` options.